# Add data after the last filled line of Google Sheets, with gspread python

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I need to add a dataframe's values to the end of the last row of records in my Google spreadsheet, but I can't. Each time I use the code below, it subscribes to the above information.
I'm using a gspread library to update the data in the Google Sheets spreadsheet.

```py
sheet.update([df_data.columns.values.tolist()] + df_data.values.tolist())
```

**I want to add new data after the last filled line.**
[image: I want to add new data after the last filled line.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about using the method of `appendRows`?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```py
sheet.update([df_data.columns.values.tolist()] + df_data.values.tolist())
```

##### To:

If you want to append the value of `[df_data.columns.values.tolist()] + df_data.values.tolist()`, how about the following modification?

```py
sheet.append_rows([df_data.columns.values.tolist()] + df_data.values.tolist(), value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

If you want to append the value of `df_data.values.tolist()`, how about the following modification?

```py
sheet.append_rows(df_data.values.tolist(), value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

#### References:

- [appendRow(rowContents) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

def GoogeSheetApi():
  SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
  KEY_PATH = "YOUR-CREDENTIAL PATH"
  SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = "YOUR-SPREAD-SHEET-ID"
 
  creds = None
  creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file(KEY_PATH,scopes=SCOPES)
  service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds)
  sheet = service.spreadsheets()
  data_for_update  = [["01/01/2000" , 1000],["01/01/2000" , 2000], ["01/01/2000" , 3000]]
  req = heet.values().append(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,range="YourSheetName!A1", valueInputOption="RAW",body={"values" : data_for_update}).execute()
  print(req)
  return "success"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be appreciated  to add additional context explaining the code ‍.